# Group by different column values and pivot

Tags: sql, pivot, group

This is my table.
[image: original table]

I want to do this.
[image: expected result]

Basically, I want to group by action (endorsed, approved and issued) column every request type but tha catch is that sometimes request type can be incomplete. like the example.

Thank you for your help.

I have tried "Group By" but can't figure it out.

Comment: Please, read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms . Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write what sort of database system you have. But one way to do it is to use CASE clauses in a MIN(). For example, assuming you are using SQL Server and the dates are datetime or date values:

```
SELECT
  "request type",
  MIN(CASE WHEN "action" = 'endorsed' THEN "date" ELSE NULL END) AS "endorsed date",
  MIN(CASE WHEN "action" = 'approved' THEN "date" ELSE NULL END) AS "approved date",
  MIN(CASE WHEN "action" = 'issued' THEN "date" ELSE NULL END) AS "issued date"
FROM table_name
GROUP BY "request type"
```

Might be more elegant solutions depending on what kind of database system you have. I wrote this SQL query to be compatible with the most database systems possible. Keep in mind that some database systems have specific requirements and might need further adjustments. For example, SQLite does not support double quotes for identifiers, so you would need to use backticks instead.

And your database system and version might have a elegant solution. But this SHOULD work for most. Unless the dates is a string value, then you might need to cast it as date or something.